# Monitor everything goes in and out of my machine

Tags: networking, security, monitor, connection, traffic

Hello I want to achieve as much security as I can on my Ubuntu machine so I want to check for suspicius connections.Any idea how to monitor network traffic on my pc? incoming and outgoing both.I also tried netstat -t -u -c and tcpdump but I want to learn if I can use a more effective tool.Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us some example of things you want to monitor?

Comment: Basicly everything might be harmful like a backdoor or a privacy issue for example someone spy on me

Comment: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) might be an option ?

Comment: Hm no because monitors entire network so its harder to spot something suspicius I prefer to monitor only my Ububtu machine

Comment: Wireshark helps you to achieve that. you can use its filters to specify what kind of traffic you want to monitor etc.

Comment: Ah ok then you know to use these filters?

Comment: I'm going to add a simple instruction as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of tools and different ways to do this. a lot of utilities like: `wireshark`, `netstat`, `nmap`, `iptraf`, `ss`, or even `lsof`. different firewalls, audit and monitoring tools can help you to achieve this purpose.

It's basically up to you what you want to achieve, what process, or kind of traffic want to monitor etc.

#### wireshark

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Then it will ask you if you want to be able to use wireshark as a normal user, say yes and add yourself to wireshark group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a username wireshark
```

logout and login, you are ready to use wireshark. just run it select your desired interface ex: `enp0s3` and click on `start capturing`, you can also do a double click on interface name. now you are able to see all the traffic going out/in throughout that interface.

You can apply filter for specific traffic type.

[image: wireshark-filters]

there are a lot of  ways to apply filters, e.g: type in: `http` press enter. now you will see all http traffics. or `ip.src == 1.2.3.4` to specify source, or `ip.dst` for destination. You also have access to expression builder, for creating complex expression to filter out your desired traffic type.

[image]

---

#### Iptables logging

You can turn on logging in iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
sudo iptables -A OUPUT -j LOG
```

Then using diffrent log managers you can watch what's going on, remember that it's going to create really huge log files, because it's going to log everything!

The better solution is to only log specific traffic which you are concern about, ex:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j LOG
```

Which logs incoming packets using TCP protocol at port 53.

---

#### netstat

You can do alot with this tool, if you want to see which ports are listening on:

```
netstat -tulnp
```

`-t`: tcp, `-u`: udp, `-n`: use number instead of names, `-l`: listening, `-p`: to know what process is listening on these ports.

Add the `grep` to to magical stuff with netstat.

```
sudo netstat -ul | grep 53
```

---

#### ss

`ss` is similar to netstat with a lot of cool options. if I want to list TCP connections from my network `192.168.1.0/24` to `151.101.1.69` (which is askubuntu IP), with destination port of 80 or 443, I can run:

```
ss -nt '( dport = :80 or dport = :443 )' src 192.168.1.0/24 dst 151.101.1.69
```

or I can see what connection has been made by `python` process:

```
ss -ap | grep python
```

---

#### nmap

with nmap I can scan a computer or network, scanning my own interface from port 80 to 800 (for open ports):

```
nmap 192.168.0.1 -p 80-800
```

Let's say my 80 port was open, I can use `-sV` switch to find out which service with what version is running at that port:

```
$ nmap 192.168.1.1 -p 80 -sV
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
80/tcp open  http    Apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since netstat and wireshark are already mentioned.

A nice starting point before you use these, can be the lsof (list open files) command, it has an -i flag that without an argument lists all internet network files.

-i (list internet network files) -P (inhibit port numbers) -n (no conversion of network numbers)

as in

```
lsof -i -P -n
```

Now that's probably a long list, and there are a lot of duplicates.
But you can trim this down

```
$ lsof -i -P -n | cut -f 1 -d " " | tail -n +2 | sort | uniq
chrome
dropbox
firefox
python
thunderbi
vim
```

While this doesn't give you much info, it's a quick overview, and if something interests you, you can investigate it further from there.

Keep in mind there can be false positives here, in my case that would be vim and python, which are caused by ycmd, a vim plugin i use that runs as a local server process.

For example, if i did not know this i could check

```
$ ps ax | grep python
```

To see all the processes, and grab a port there and check netstat.

```
$ netstat -p | grep 51635
tcp        1      0 localhost:41792         localhost:51635         CLOSE_WAIT  27413/vim
```

And, as mentioned this is a loopback route from ycmd, so, not actually going outside my machine. 
But now i know.